# Smtp Exception need perfect answers

Tags: smtpclient

I have this code which was working perfectly a few months ago. Now it throws two exceptions.

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 199.168.188.194:25

1. System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'Failure sending mail' -WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server
2. SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

   ```
   MailMessage email_msg = new MailMessage("test@email.com", "test@email.com", "Order Confirm", "Dear ss! your Order Has Been Confirmed. Thanx For Shoping");
   email_msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
   SmtpClient mailclient = new SmtpClient();
   System.Net.NetworkCredential basic = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
   mailclient.Host = "mail.testdeva.com";
   mailclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
   mailclient.Credentials = basic;
   mailclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
   mailclient.Send(email_msg);

   email_msg.Dispose();
   email_msg = null;
   mailclient.Dispose();
   mailclient = null;
   ```

Really appreciate the answers

Comment: Is the server at 199.168.188.194 still there? If yes, is the smtp server still listening on port 25?

Comment: i have ping the server via cmd and there is no packet lose.